# Kingfisher load cache image

Tags: ios, swift, kingfisher

My API returns 2 types of photo: small and big

I use kingfisher to load photos and I always load small photo first. When I load big photo I want to achieve this

```
if hasCacheSmallPhoto {
  imageView.kf.setImage(with: bigImageUrl, placeholder: cacheImage)
} else {
  imageView.kf.setImage(with: bigImageUrl, placeholder: defaultPlaceHolderImage)
}
```

How can I properly achieve that using kingfisher

Answer (score 0):

you need to check first if small image is cached by kingFisher Cache.

```
    if ImageCache.default.isCached(forKey:smallImageUrl) {

     ImageCache.default.retrieveImage(forKey: smallImageUrl) { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let value):

       imageView.kf.setImage(with: bigImageUrl, placeholder: value.image)

    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
}   
}
else {
     imageView.image = defaultPlaceHolderImage
     imageView.kf.setImage(with: smallImageUrl) { result in
    // `result` is either a `.success(RetrieveImageResult)` or a `.failure(KingfisherError)`
    switch result {
    case .success(let value):
        // The image was set to image view:
        imageView.kf.setImage(with: bigImageUrl, placeholder: value.image)


        // The source object which contains information like `url`.
        print(value.source)

    case .failure(let error):
        print(error) // The error happens
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If I am not wrong you want to display small image first and when big image downloaded successfully you want to replace small image with big image right?

Comment: Yes, it is the cached image right. Because I download it before, so the same url should be cached

Comment: I have Updated my answer please check may be it will help you.